# Orthogonal complements in arbitrary normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I'm struggling to follow a certain proof in Luenberger's book "Optimization by Vector Space Methods". If anyone could help shed some light on what I'm missing, I would certainly appreciate it. Let me start with a couple of definitions.

**Definition 1**  Let $S$ be a subset of a normed linear space $X$. The orthogonal
complement of $S$, denoted $S^\perp$, consists of all elements $x^* \in X^*$ ($X^*$ denotes the continuous dual space) orthogonal to every vector in $S$.

**Definition 2** Given a subset $U$ of the dual space $X^*$, we define the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $X$ as the set $^\perp U \subset X$ consisting of all elements in $X$ orthogonal to every vector in $U$.

**Definition 3** The vectors $x \in X$ and $x^* \in X^*$ are said to be orthogonal if $\langle x, x^*\rangle =0$.
$\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the dual pairing.

**Theorem** Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a normed space $X$. Then
$^\perp[M^\perp] = M$.

**Proof** It is clear that $M \subset{}^\perp[M^\perp]$. To prove the converse, let $x \notin M$. On the subspace $[x + M]$ generated by $x$ and $M$, define the linear functional $f(\alpha x + m) = \alpha $ for $m \in M$. Then
\begin{equation}
\|\,f\|=\sup_{m\in M}\frac{f(x+m)}{\|x+m\|}=\frac{1}{\inf_{m}\|x+m\|}
\end{equation}
and since $M$ is closed, $\|\,f\| < \infty$. Thus by the Hahn-Banach theorem, we
can extend $f$ to an $x^* \in X^*$. Since $f$ vanishes on M, we have $x^* \in M^\perp$ But also $\langle x, x^*\rangle = 1$ and thus $x \notin{}^\perp[M^\perp]$.

**Comments** I'm struggling to understand the necessity of the subspace being closed. Would bounded not suffice?

My understanding of the proof is as follows. Using the definition of the norm of an $f$ in the dual space and positivity we get the first equality in the displayed equation. Noticing that $\alpha=1$ and interchanging $\sup$ and $\inf$ by taking the $\inf$ into the denominator gives the second equality. I would have thought from here we would be able to guarantee finiteness of the norm. We then use the Hahn-Banach Theorem to extend $f$ to $x^* \in X^*$. Then using $\alpha=0$ implies $f=0$ on $M$. Thus $f(x_1)=\langle x^*,x_1\rangle=0$ where $x_1 \in M$ so they are orthogonal. However, $\alpha=1$ implies $f(x)=1=\langle x^*,x\rangle$ hence $x \notin{}^\perp[M^\perp]$.

Comment: Which subspace of $X$ is bounded?

Comment: Check out [my edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2887791/revisions) to see how to prevent a left superscript from being attached to the symbol to its left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is not closed, then for each $x \in \overline{M} \backslash M$ there is a sequence $(m_n)$ in $M$ such that $\lVert x - m_n \rVert \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But then $\inf_m \lVert x + m \rVert = 0$ since $-m_n \in M$.

Note that no linear subspace except the trivial one (having $0$ as its only element) is bounded.

Comment: I see. Sorry. I realise now that that was a somewhat silly thing not to notice.  Thanks.